# Making Custom Field Required

Tags: formula, custom-field, required-field, required

I am trying to make a field required. I used an "ifblank" validation rule which returned an error if blank, this worked. However, this does not allow another field to be entered as the other one is returning blank. I need to find a way to make this ifblank rule run after the other field is populated. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want it always required, configuring the field itself to be required is by far the most correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the field required:

1. At the "database level", by setting it as requiring a value in the Field's definition.
2. At the "page layout level", by setting it as required by using the "spanner" in the layout editor next to the field.
3. Using a validation rule.
4. In Dynamic Forms, by setting it as required using the lightning app builder property editor.

The first three options can be found in the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323820&type=1). The last one is covered [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_req_fields.htm&type=5).

If you need to make the required nature of the field vary based on another value, the validation rule is the easiest approach, and is covered [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324555&type=1).

Comment: I should mention that the first two options will not work because the field is managed so I cannot click required. When making a validation rule based on another value is it able to do this based on if another field is blank or not?

Comment: Yes, of course. Simply use IF as part of the validation formula.

Comment: But you are wrong that you cannot set it required in a page layout just because it comes from a managed package. You can.